# Font-family change in magento2

Tags: magento2, css

I am unable to change the font-family

Can any one help me to change the font-family for total site in magento 2.

Answer (score 1):

**Include locally stored fonts**

To include a custom font stored locally, use one of the following approaches:

If you build a theme using Magento UI library, declare the font by adding the .lib-font-face mixin in the `<theme_dir>/web/css/source/_typography.less` file:

```
.lib-font-face(
    @family-name:'<any_font_name>',
    @font-path: '@{baseDir}fonts/<path_to_font_file>',
    @font-weight: <font_weight>,
    @font-style: <font_style>
)
```

Where:

```
{@baseDir} stands for the app/design/frontend/<Vendor>/<theme>/web directory.

<path_to_font_file> includes the font file name, but without the extension. For example, @font-path: '@{baseDir}fonts/Luma-Icons' for the font stored in web/fonts/Luma-Icons.woff
```

The mixin generates the CSS including font. For example, here is how the generated CSS looks for the Open Sans font used in the Blank theme:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'Open Sans';
    src: url('../fonts/opensans/light/opensans-300.eot');
    src: url('../fonts/opensans/light/opensans-300.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'), url('../fonts/opensans/light/opensans-300.woff2') format('woff2'), url('../fonts/opensans/light/opensans-300.woff') format('woff'), url('../fonts/opensans/light/opensans-300.ttf') format('truetype'), url('../fonts/opensans/light/opensans-300.svg#Open Sans') format('svg');
    font-weight: 300;
    font-style: normal
}
```

If your theme does not use the Magento UI library, include the font in your theme .css files by the standard means of CSS, for example the @font-face rule.